# Set the limits of x-axis in both ggplot line graph and slider range

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below:

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE), y=sample(20:30, 10, replace=TRUE))
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)
```

from which I want to create a line graph which will begin from the minimum value of `x` and will end to the maximum value of `x` in the `x-axis`. The issue is that while Im using `limits` I still get values lower than 1 and bigger than 3 in the `x-axis` of my plot. I tried to remove the slider range but the issue remains.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y))  + geom_line( colour="#00A0BD")+scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1", "2", "3")) + xlab("Year") + ylab("Total Headcount") + ylim(0, 50)) %>% 
  rangeslider()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was interesting to debug - I hadn't worked with ggplotly and rangeslider before.

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE), y=sample(20:30, 10, replace=TRUE))

df_new <-
  df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(
    ymin = min(y),
    ymax = max(y)
  )

p <- 
  df_new %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = ymin, yend = ymax)) +
  geom_segment() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 2, 3)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 50))

ggplotly(p) %>% 
  rangeslider(start = 0.5, end = 3.5)
```

First, you'll want to take out the factor call on the x axis. You can use `geom_segment` after creating a summary table of the minimum and maximum y-value for each x to get the lines plotted. Then the `start` and `end` arguments can be used in `rangeslider` to choose the limits of the x-axis.

Comment: I get error while creating df_new- error in summarize(., ymin = min(y), ymax = max(y)) : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be happening - I started a fresh R session and the code worked after importing tidyverse and plotly.

Comment: ok just needed tidyverse instead of Hmisc but now Im getting : Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale after ploting the graph with your method.

Comment: oh that happened because x was a factor

Comment: I will accept your answer for this specific dataset form but Im going to create a new Q with a dataset which is closer to my original